# Keras takes long time to go to next epoch

Tags: performance, tensorflow, keras, epoch

While training the CNN, after completion of each epoch it takes more time to move to next epoch, while each epoch can be completed in 60s-80s, it take almost 5 mins to move to next epoch. I have provided my code, is there anything I am missing out ?

```
#importing the libraries

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

#inintializing the ANN

classifier = Sequential()

# Convolutional layer

classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape =(128, 128, 3), activation = 'relu'))

#pooling layer
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

#second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

# flatten
classifier.add(Flatten())

#full connection
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

#compiling the cnn
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# we create two instances with the same arguments
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (128, 128),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (128, 128),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         samples_per_epoch = 8000,
                         nb_epoch = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         nb_val_samples = 2000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to set `samples_per_epoch` and `nb_val_samples` if you use ImageDataGenerator, as this is a Sequence and internally contains its length (if you use a recent Keras version, of course). The problem is that `nb_val_steps` is used for the parameter `validation_steps`, and I think you just set this value much higher than the right value.

If needed, you should set `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` to the correct values, if you set `validation_steps` to a value larget than `len(val_data) / batch_size`, you are effectively telling keras to do validation with more data than necessary, slowing down the validation step.